# On sparse complete sets and P vs L

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, reductions, polynomial-time, logspace

Mahaney's Theorem tells us that if there is a sparse $NP$-complete set under polynomial-time many-one reductions, then $P = NP$.  (See "[Sparse complete sets for NP: Solution of a conjecture of Berman and Hartmanis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000082900022)")

Are there known consequences of the existence of sparse complete sets for other complexity classes?  In particular, if there is a sparse $P$-complete set under logspace many-one reductions, does that imply $P = L$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, exactly what you suggested is true: if there is a sparse $\mathbf{P}$-complete set under log-space many-one reductions, then $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{L}$. This was conjectured by Hartmanis in 1978 and proven by Cai and Sivakumar in 1995. See [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/492492/).

Hartmanis also conjectured that if there is a sparse $\mathbf{NL}$-complete set under log-space many-one reductions, then $\mathbf{NL} = \mathbf{L}$. This was also proven by Cai and Sivakumar in 1997; see [this other paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/papers/NL.pdf).

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much!!  This is great.  :)